Finding point $S$
I have $f: x\mapsto 2x\ln(\frac{x}{2})$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$. Let $E (x_E \mid y_E)$ be the extremal point. The restriction of $f$ to the interval $]0; x_E]$ has the inverse function $g_1$, the restriction of $f$ to the interval $[x_E; \infty[$ has the inverse function $g_2.$

The graphs of $f$ and $g_2$ have the point $S(x_S \mid y_S)$ in common. Calculate the coordinates of $S$.

So I tried to calculate the inverse function.
$$
\frac{y}{2}=x\ln \frac{x}{2}
$$
$$
\exp \frac{y}{2} = \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^x
$$
This makes no sense...
Can someone help me find the point $S$?

Maybe $y=x$ can help you :)

The graph of the inverse function $g_1$ is created by mirroring the graph $G_f$ (restricted to the interval $] 0 ; x_E[$ ) at the angle bisector $y=x$.

So just determine the point of intersection $S$ between $f$ and the angle bisector $y=x$. Divide first by $2x$ which is possible as $x\neq{0}$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
2 x \cdot \ln \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)&=x\\
 \ln \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)&=\frac{1}{2}\\
 \frac{x}{2}&=e^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
 \rightarrow \quad x^S&=2 e^{\frac{1}{2}}=2 \sqrt{e} \\
 y^S&=f\left(x^S\right)=f(2 \sqrt{e})=4 \sqrt{e} \ln (\sqrt{e}).
\end{aligned}
$$
Here
$$
\ln (\sqrt{e})=\ln \left(e^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2} \underbrace{\ln e}_1=\frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
\rightarrow \quad y^S=2 \sqrt{e}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \quad S(2 \sqrt{e} \mid 2 \sqrt{e})
$$
